# How to use two collectionview in one tableview

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have two collectionviews inside tableviewcell. I have set the first one and it works greats. The problem is i dont know how to call second collectionview in datasource protocol functions.

P.S i have used ashfurrow`s tutorial for the first one.

Comment: How complex is your UI that you need to nest CollectionViews inside a TableView cell?

Comment: @jervine10 it is almost like a facebook timeline. i have two collectionviews for each tableviewcell.

Comment: You're going to have to post code samples of what you have, and perhaps a screenshot of the design you want to build.

Comment: I am already on the half way of solving my issue. if i will solve it by myself i will post the solution.

Comment: @jervine10 i just want to set two different collectionview with different data inside one tableviewcell.

Answer (score 0):

In collection view datasource methods, you need to check the collection view reference for which the method is called ,i.e,

**Example**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   if collectionView === self.collectionView1
   {
      //code for 1st collection view
   }
   else if collectionView === self.collectionView2
   {
      //code for 2nd collection view
   }
}
```

Apply same check in other collection view datasource methods.